Извлечь несколько значений ключей из списка словарей
Нужно из списка словарей, где есть разные ключи: имена, возраст, пол, вывести только имена и возраст. Знаю как достать из списка со словарем значение, а как достать сразу несколько?
name = {'name_1': 'Vitalik', 'name_2': 'Andrey', 'age_1': 19, 'age_2': 15]}
for names in name:
    if names['name_1'] == 'Vitalik':
        print(names['name_1'])

как можно найти и вывести сразу два имени?
или вот код:
a=[{'a': 'qq', 'b': 'ww'}]
a[0]['b']


'ww'

он находит.
Но как или через цикл или через второй код найти два и более ключа и вывести их значения? чтоб не писать для каждого ключа новый цикл?

Показывайте структуру данных, свой код.

Отредактируйте вопрос. Используйте отформатированный код

Показывайте настоящий код

я спросил, и пример показал что хочу сделать

в цифре ошибся.

так можно так сделать или нужно для каждого раза писать новый цикл?

Пожалуйста, попробуйте более ясно выразить, чего вы хотите. Я стараюсь понять вас, но пока безуспешно.

мне нужно вывести через print все имена и возраст, но хочу сделать так чтоб можно было достать сразу два значения или все, чтоб не писать для 'name_1' 'name_2' чтоб вот например достать значения трех ключей сразу

Что такое name v вашем коде? В первой строке это ни список, ни словарь, во второй какое-то имя пользователя, в третьей опять словарь или список, ...

a=[{'a': 'qq', 'b': 'ww'}]
a[0]['b']             можно ли например как-то написать этот код чтоб вывел ключ и a и b одним выражением, и через цикл можно ли это сделать?

Пожалуйста, не объясняйте в комментарии, а добавите прямо до вопроса.

Вас просят привести пример настоящего словаря "есть разные ключи, имена, возраст, пол, " и показать пример желаемого результата, а не этот бред

исправил код в вопросе

где бред? дан список в нем словарь, в котором 4 ключа, я хочу получить значения четырех ключей одним циклом

Когда вы хотите от нас получить помощь, постарайтесь, пожалуйста, помочь нам понять, чего вы хотите достичь. Мы хотим, но всё время вас не понимаем.

я написал чего хочу, да есть остальной задание, но дальше я хочу сам его выполнить, зачем мне чтоб вы за меня все сделали, изначально стоит вопрос выввести через print в консоль из списка все имена и возраст их

Бред состоит в том, что вы только повторяете, что вы уже написали, не давая никаких новых информаций.

вы можете ответить как из списка получить значения четырех ключей одним циклом?

for k in names: print(k, names[k])

я хочу иметь возможность значения каких ключей, например хочу вывести значения первых трех ключей

Я думаю, что вы хотите это:
names = {'name_1': 'Vitalik', 'name_2': 'Andrey', 'age_1': 19, 'age_2': 15}

for key in 'name_1', 'age_2':
    print(names[key])

Вывод:

Vitalik
15



Объяснение:
В команде for key in 'name_1', 'age_2': перечисленны только те ключи, которых значения вы хотите получить.

тут все ключи, а нужно указать значения каких ключей получить

@vitaliy, я изменил мой ответ, чтобы он соответствовал вашим требованиям.

спасибо, вроде понял
